# reading from STDIN, Chicken Scheme

Tags: c, pipe, stdin, zsh, chicken-scheme

I know how to (more or less) do this in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char buf[BUFSIZ];
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); // reads STDIN into buffer `buf` line by line
  if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == '\n')
  {
    printf("%s", buf);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The desired end result being to read STDIN from a pipe, if present.  (I know the above code doesn't do that, but I couldn't figure out how to only do the above when reading from a pipe/heredoc).

How would I do something similar in *Chicken* Scheme?

Like I said before, the end goal is to be able to do this:

```bash
echo 'a' | ./read-stdin
# a

./read-stdin << EOF
a
EOF
# a

./read-stdin <<< "a"
 # a

./read-stdin <(echo "a")
 # a

./read-stdin < <(echo "a")
 # a
```

Comment: Once any one of the first three works, the other two will work.  The fourth one provides a file name on the command line that the `read-stdin` program would have to open and read.  Maybe you meant to write: `./read-stdin < <(echo "a")` which redirects to standard input; then once one works, they all work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what does that have to do with anything?  The zsh examples with `read-stdin` are just that: examples.  In zsh both `cat < <(echo a)` and `cat <(echo a)` have the same result.  I don't actually have a `read-stdin` program that actually does the above, I was just trying to illustrate what the end result was supposed to be.

Comment: There is a difference between `cat < <(echo a)` and `cat <(echo a)`; in the first, the shell opens the file, but in the second `cat` does.  So, the last example requires different action from your putative `read-stdin` program from the other examples.  Other than that, it doesn't progress you towards an answer, I'm afraid.  I'd help if I knew anything of Chicken Scheme but I'd never heard of it before your question, and I know little enough about Scheme (but I have sort of used it for things barely more complex than 'hello world').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```scm
;; read-stdin.scm

(use posix)
;; let me know if STDIN is coming from a terminal or a pipe/file
(if (terminal-port? (current-input-port))
   (fprintf (current-error-port) "~A~%" "stdin is a terminal") ;; prints to stderr
   (fprintf (current-error-port) "~A~%" "stdin is a pipe or file"))
;; read from STDIN
(do ((c (read-char) (read-char)))
   ((eof-object? c))
   (printf "~C" c))
(newline)
```

According to the Chicken [wiki](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20posix#how-scheme-procedures-relate-to-unix-c-functions), `terminal-port?` is Chicken's equivalent to C's `isatty()` function.

**NOTE**

The above example works *best* when compiled.  Running it with `csi` seems to make `terminal-port?` always return true, but perhaps adding an explicit call to `(exit)` and th end of the file would cause the Chicken Scheme interpreter to exit, thus allowing `STDIN` to be something other than a terminal?